# Chrome Virus - Bueno Search

Tags: google-chrome, malware

Today I suddenly had my new tabs overidden by the "buenosearch" website with no new extensions or apps installed.

I have followed all steps I can find online to remove this but it continues to come back. I have run Bit Defender's Antivirus for Mac, and am now running MacScan and Clam Xav to try and remove it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should have just googled it: http://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-bueno-search/. A) It's not a virus. B) It does not affect OS X. C) It's simply a chrome extension. Remove it from Chrome and you are good. Running all those AntiVirus software will do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I went straight to 3dnator extension, and disabled it... It just worked! :)

Comment: Can you explain how you did that?

Comment: Removed 3d- nator and it owrked for me too

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I'm guessing you also downloaded the 3d function for Google Chrome as an extension. Delete it—that has the virus in it. That should fix the problem, I hope it works for you to.

Answer (score 0):

I did it. What I did is very simple:

1. Disable all extensions.
2. Open a new tab and check if the bueno has disappeared.
3. If it disappeared, reactivate extensions one after another and check every time if the bueno appeared.
4. When it appears, remove the extension that is responsible for it.
5. Try all extensions - it may be one of your old known extensions as it happened with me.